# async call in jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My web app has a master jade template that contains all the main components that need to be loaded on EVERY page of the app. One of these components is a navbar which I've split out into another template. This navbar has a dropdown that needs to be populated dynamically from a DB.

The problem I'm having is that I want to populate the dropdown at the time that the navbar gets rendered. Because I'm using express 4.0 with nodeJS, I thought of using a helper function that would populate the list straight from within the navbar template. Because this function is async though, the navbar renders itself before the dropdown items are retrieved from the DB.

I also thought of using AJAX on the page load to populate it or even just passing the dropdown items into the template beforehand but I don't want to have to pass in this list on every single res.render() call in my controllers.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

### Sample templates

`master.jade:`

```
doctype html
html(lang=en)
head
    block title
body
    #header
        include navbar
        block headerContent
    #content
        block content
```

`navbar.jade:`

```
... //nav code

li(class='dropdown')
  a(href='#', class='dropdown-toggle', data-toggle='dropdown') List
    span(class='caret')
      ul(class='dropdown-menu', role='menu')
        li
          each val, index in list
            a(href='#') val
```

A typical page in the system would just extend the master template and fill in the appropriate header and content blocks.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Adding a sample controller to show render call

`sampleController.js:`

```
...some error checking
model.save(function(err, results) {
   if (err)
      res.render('view', {error: 'some error'})
   else
      res.render('view', {data: *formatted results obj*})
```

The data specifically relates with the content that should be rendered on this particular view and not necessarily what's required by the master. I don't want to have to pass in the navbar items as well.

Comment: Is the navbar different for each user? Does it depend on some state?

Comment: show the render call on your server and the variables you are passing.

Comment: @bebraw Right now it's the same navbar for every user. I haven't incorporated sessions or anything yet.

Comment: @ravi updated the question to show sample render call

Comment: @hebime i don't see the `list` variable, you are passing `data` variable through your server.

Comment: @ravi That's correct. I don't want to have to pass list in every res.render() call

Comment: @hebime then use the solution below, and if you have doubt, Google middleware handlers in express.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks, I went with that solution seems to fit pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX seems impractical for a navbar.

You can use a middlewear to populate locals object

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.list = [...];
    // or 
    app.locals.list = [...];
    next();
});
```